# Uncaught TypeError: tags.join is not a function

Tags: reactjs, arraylist

I have a page which have multiple tags stored in an array. I want to edit that page and when trying to load the array of tags into the TagsInput, getting the below error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tags.join is not a function
```

Here is the code snip related to this error:

```
import { TagsInput } from "react-tag-input-component";

const UpdatePage = () => {

  const [tags, setTags] = useState("");
  const tagsString = tags.join(", ");

  // Fetching tags from backend and storing into setTags
  setTags(<some_code_for_axios_get>) 

  return(
    <div>
        <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
          <TagsInput
            label="Tags"
            size="small"
            value={tagsString}
            onChange={setTags}
            placeHolder="Type your tag and press enter"
          />
        </FormControl>
    </div>
 )

}
```

Also tried the following and got the `n.map not a function` error message:

```
<div className="tags">
  {tags.length
    ? tags.map((type, i) => (
      <TagsInput
        key={i}
        label="Tags"
        size="small"
        value={i}
        onChange={setTags}
        placeHolder="Type your tag and press enter"
      />
      ))
    : <TagsInput
        label="Tags"
        size="small"
        value={tags}
        onChange={setTags}
        placeHolder="Type your tag and press enter"
      />
    }
</div>
```

using the below, I can see the data in the console:

```
 tags.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags are not an array, they are a string, as per this line:

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState("");
```

Regardless of what happens here `setTags(<some_code_for_axios_get>)`, the first render, `tags` will be `""`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the useState to 'useState([])' to use it as an array type but still the issue is same. And I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: n.map is not a function" error message now.

Comment: what is in setTags?

Comment: Let say setTags is having ['javascript', 'react'] in it and I want to open that again during the time of edit of the page, so that some one can add or remove the tags.

Comment: not use join(' ,') ... in <TagsInput  value={tags}

Comment: If you still receive the issue about join is not a function, something is up with setTags (like @NaveenNizam said). Can you update your question to include updated code, including how setTags is used

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chris and Naveen for point towards the solution. After making the following changes, it worked as expected:

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

<FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
  <TagsInput
    label="Tags"
    size="small"
    value={tags}
    onChange={setTags}
    placeHolder="Type your tag and press enter"
  />
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use useEffect so that your code will work properly, and there is no need to use join; you can directly send an array to that component.

```
import { TagsInput } from "react-tag-input-component";

const UpdatePage = () => {

  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  // don't need to join tags
  // const tagsString = tags.join(", ");

  // Fetching tags from backend and storing into setTags
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTags(<some_code_for_axios_get>)
  }, [<add dependencies according to your code>]);
   
  return(
    <div>
        <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
          <TagsInput
            label="Tags"
            size="small"
            value={tagsString}
            onChange={setTags}
            placeHolder="Type your tag and press enter"
          />
        </FormControl>
    </div>
 )

}
```

Comment: thank you. I am already using the useEffect the way you have explained. In this example, I have not added that as it was specific to TagsInput only :)

Comment: okay not an issue!